# How do you pass an array of structs into a function?

Tags: c++

Suppose we have:

```
struct elements{
    string drink_name;
    double price_per_can;
    double number_in_machine;
};

struct elements machine[6];
```

And machine is populated in main(). How do I pass machine into a function (by reference) to be used inside the function?

Comment: Consider using `std::array` instead of a naked fixed length array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass it as a reference:

```
void foo(elements (&x)[6])
{
    x[1].price_per_can = 1.8;
    x[4].drink_name = "mom's breakfast juice";
}

int main()
{
    elements machine[6];
    foo(machine);
}
```

Comment: Why am I passing elements into foo() instead of machine?

Comment: He probably meant machine.

Comment: @user3064097: Sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::array<elements, 6> machine_c2;

// Edit: Removed const
// Edit: Reflect edit by other user
//        and add consistency with machine.begin()
void doSomething(std::array<elements, 6>& machine) {
    std::cout << machine.begin()->drink_name;
    machine.begin()->drink_name = "Cherry";
}

int main() {
    machine_c2.begin()->drink_name = "Strawberry";
    doSomething(machine_c2);
    std::cout << machine_c2.begin()->drink_name;
    return 0;
}
```